# getSize() is undefined for Collection?

Tags: java, methods, collections, get

Here's the code in question (these methods are in the same class):

```
private int size;

public int getSize(){
    return this.size;
}
public boolean addAll(Collection c) {

    Iterator iter = c.iterator();
    int i =0;
    while(i < c.getSize()){
        add(iter.next()); // This part isn't finished yet
        i++;
        this.size++;
    }
```

I'm receiving the error where I called c.getSize(). The error is: c.getSize() is undefined for type Collection.

Comment: Did you consider consulting the Javadoc, instead of just guessing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method name is `size()`, not `getSize()`. See [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html).

Comment: why can't I add a manual get/set method then? Does it not like it since it isn't guaranteed to be in the Collection in the parameter?

Comment: You can add getSize() to your own class, but you are calling it on a Collection, not your own class. Your code seems pretty confused about what it is actually doing. You have an Iterator, use *its* methods to tell you whether there is anything left in the iteration.

Comment: @user2489837 - The fact that you have defined a `getSize()` in your own class is kind of irrelevant. Even if `c` is an instance of the class you are defining and it has a `getSize()` method, the compiler does not know that because the method parameter does not declare `c` to be any specific subclass of `Collection`.

Comment: Ok, thank you...I know the question is stupid but I'm new to LinkedLists and their associated errors. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In collection there is no method with name "getSize()" But you can use size() method to get the size of the collection.